# How can I detect std::thread was terminated as async?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm a Java engineer but I need to migrate my Java code to C++.

In C++:

```
void foo(){
    thread t(&loading_function);
    t.detach();
}

void loading_function(){
    while(true){
    //..some loading operations
    }
}

//I want to call after loading_function NOT in main thread like t.join();
void loading_after(){  
    //..loading after handling
}
```

I want to handling after thread `t` was end of its process.

Like this Java code:

```
public class Test implements Runnable{
    public void foo(){
        Thread loading_thread = new Thread(this);
        loading_thread.start();
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            //..some loading operations
        }
        loading_after();
    }

    public void loading_after(){
        //..loading after handling
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: In java, in which thread is `loading_after()` called?

Comment: @Pratik Please don't mark random bits of text that aren't code as if they were code. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text. (It's not entirely your fault, the reviewers were supposed to catch that too.)

Comment: @rozina it would be main thread better than background thread.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description on how `std::thread::detach()` works, I don't think you can detect when it ends, unless you make your `loading_function()` signal to the outside world that is has ended. There seems to be no built in mechanism for a detached `std::thread` to signal it has ended. I might be wrong, I have little experience with `std::thread`.

Alternative would be to make a function that does both `loading_function()` and `loading_after()` and pass that function to the `std::thread` object.

```
void loading_function()
{
    while(true)
    {
        //..some loading operations
    }
}

//I want to call after loading_function NOT in main thread like t.join();
void loading_after()
{  
    //..loading after handling
}

void load()
{
    loading_function();
    loading_after();
}

void foo()
{
    thread t(&load);
    t.detach();
}
```

Comment: thanks! it helps me. but is it possible to loading_after function in main thread?

Comment: @LaLaAsDev One way you could do it is for `loading_function()` to somehow signal the main thread that it has finished. Send an event or something. Depends on what is available in your application. I don't know of any standard way of doing it.

Comment: thanks your comment. I'll find standard way for this process~